# How to fill number of remaining character in string using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have following query to add remaining leading character in a string

```
PRINT REPLACE(STR('9009',8),' ','X')
```

Output

```
XXXX9009
```

I need output like this

```
9009XXXX
```

Please help is there any builtin function available in SQL Server 2008

Comment: stuff https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of 2 `REVERSE` function.

**Query**

```
PRINT REPLACE(reverse(STR(reverse('9009'),8)),' ','X');
```

**Output**

```
9009XXXX
```

**[Find demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/654820/how-to-fill-number-of-remaining-charter-in-string-using-sql-server)**

### **Update**

You can use `REPLICATE`.

**Query**

```
declare @str as varchar(4) = 'WTRR';
print @str + replicate('X', 8 - len(@str))
```

**Output**

```
WTRRXXXX
```

Comment: I observe currently that 'STR' function does not work if my input is string like instead of '9009' I entered 'WTRR' then it throws error, is there any other function available that can handle alphanumeric value as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Substring:

```
 declare @s varchar(30)
set @s = 'XXXX9009';
select  SUBSTRING (@s ,5 , 4)  + SUBSTRING (@s ,1 , 4)
```

result:

```
9009XXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the way to do it for alphanumeric value also.

```
PRINT LEFT('ABSWW' + REPLICATE('X',18) ,18)
```

Output

```
ABSWWXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```